# In Windows XP Professional, is there a limit on the number of files that can be contained in a single folder?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems

I am running Windows XP Professional, service pack 3.  Right now I have **4,398 files** in a single folder, and Windows XP seems to read it fine.  How many more files can I place in this same folder, either *theoretically* or *practically*?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is taken from one of the sister sites at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many) and is copied here for your convenience.

#### FAT32:

- Maximum number of files: 268,435,437
- Maximum file size: 4GB
- Maximum number of files per directory: up to 65535, or less depending on file names

#### NTFS:

- Maximum number of files: 4,294,967,295
- Maximum file size: 16TB currently (16EB theoretically)

FAT32 has a limit of 65535 files per directory. As for non-FAT32, I could not find a "hard limit", but the information in this [comparison chart](http://www.frank4dd.com/howto/various/maxfiles-per-dir.htm) is quite informative.

Comment: Your exercise in copy-and-paste resulted in loss of information (e.g., which 'comparison chart'?).

Comment: Thanks!  I am using NTFS.  It looks like I don't have to worry about exceeding the limit!  :-)